# Add local external jar - should not point at files within the project directory

Tags: maven

In my maven project I use custom external `my-custom-external` jar like this:

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-custom-external</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/my-custom-external-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I success build project my `mvn verify` but in console I has warning:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.myproject:prj_1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.myproject:my-custom-extneral:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/libs/my-custom-extneral-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 62, column 25
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

Comment: I would try hard to avoid systemPath dependencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is just a warning and you are okay to do this as long as it is used only in this project as it won't be visible for the dependent projects.

You can consider below two options for doing it right

1. Install the 3rd party jar to your local repository and reference it just like any other dependency. Refer to [this link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for more details on installing the library
2. If you want to refer it from your project, then add your project `libs` folder as a repository as shown below

   ```
   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>localrepository</id>
           <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
       </repository>
       .
       .
       .
       .
   </repositories>
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: Second approach not help.Same warning.

Comment: thats strange, have you removed the `systemPath` attribute? 1st option would be ideal

Comment: If I remove <dependency>
           <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/my-custom-external-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath> then  I get error: [WARNING] The POM for com.myproject:my-custom-external:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from localrepository: file:xxx

Comment: Did you add the `libs` folder as a `repository`?

Comment: <repository>
            <id>localrepository</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
        </repository>  - not help

Comment: Not sure why adding lib folder as local repository is not working for you, but glad it is resolved with the first approach

Comment: Just came across this answer, in order to make libs as a local repository mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file://.. should be executed first. Otherwise it wont work

Comment: I am very late to the discussion. But thank you, @Prasann. I have added a new answer, combining your suggestion with something else I tried. Please feel free to review.

Comment: This doesnt make sense. If the original with SystemPath cannot resolve ${project.baseDir}  for dependant projects, why will it resolve when you use ${project.basedir} in a <repository>?

Answer (score 50):

you can use ${pom.basedir} to replace ${project.basedir}

Comment: I have another issue also so could you please check my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66527267/external-jars-not-found-while-running-the-application

Comment: It worked but builded jar still not include libs

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation? pom.basedir is actually deprecated... https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-model-builder/

Comment: This has worked for me

Answer (score 8):

*I reached here because I faced a similar problem. And based on [this answer by Prasann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55183608/2620467), I think I have a viable solution for this that will resolve most issues. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.*

*Credit for the CheckSum related steps : [Casey Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945261/2620467)*

1. During development, install the local external jar.

   To do this, run the following command

   `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar -DcreateChecksum=true`

   Fields inside `<` and `>` (including the `<` and `>`) need to be replaced with actual values.
2. Rename the `maven-metadata-local` files that are generated to remove the `local` part.
3. Copy the entire folder for this jar file (*I'll call this as* **installed folder**) from your local Maven repository to your project's `lib` folder. You need to maintain the folder structure from the root of the Maven repository.

   For example, if the absolute path for your **installed folder** is `C:\Users\so_user\.m2\repository\my_group_id\my_artifact_id\`, then your project lib folder should also look like `${project.basedir}\lib\my_group_id\my_artifact_id\`.

   Also note that,

   - `my_group_id` in this point is the same as `<group-id>` in point #2. Just replace any periods (.) with a slash (\).
   - `my_artifact_id` in this point is the same as `<artifact-id>` in point #2. No changes required for this.
4. In your `pom.xml` file, create a local repository by adding the following lines:

   ```
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>any_name</id>
         <name>Any Name</name>
         <url>file://[path-to-lib-folder]</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
   ```

   - You can choose any name for `id` and `name`.
   - Replace `[path-to-lib-folder]` with the actual folder path. You can use `${project.basedir}` or `${pom.basedir}` here. No warning will pop up.
5. Add a dependency to the external jar as normal.

   ```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>[group-id]</groupId>
         <artifactId>[artifact-id]</artifactId>
         <version>[version]</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

   Replace `[group-id]`, `[artifact-id]` and `[version]` with the actual values from point #1.

Because you have provided the entire **installed folder** in your project `lib` folder, you do not need to run `mvn install:install-file` again when you transfer this project to a new system.