# External jars not found while running the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

In my project, I have some external jars. So I added those jars in project libs folders also.

I refer : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_external_dependencies.htm

If I am running my project in eclipse so it is working as expected but when I created .jar file and tried to ran through .bat file it gave me throws me error.

1. APIFactory.class is present in one of my external jar file.
2. I think the problem present in maven packaging due to that jar was not includes in executable jar file. But I tried and search so many nut I didn't got any specific answers.

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/theice/cfapi/net/APIFactory
        at com.theice.cfapi.client.ClientSample.createConnection(ClientSample.java:320)
        at com.orion.service.RequestDataService.requestMarketData(RequestDataService.java:37)
        at com.orion.main.OrionController.loadPrperty(OrionController.java:23)
        at com.orion.main.MainOrionClass.main(MainOrionClass.java:26)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.theice.cfapi.net.APIFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.orion</groupId>
    <artifactId>DataFeed</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DataFeed</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- api-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-client</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/libs/api-client-1.1.0.10.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                    <mainClass> com.orion.main.MainOrionClass
                    </mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: if you follow this advice, does it help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320920/2583044

Comment: Avoid system dependencies and lib folders in Maven.

Comment: then how can I add them ?

Comment: @62mkv...by using your suggestion I can able to solve my issue.